# Looping an array within an object and manipulating the object data based on array values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this really painful task which i would like to share it with more experienced developers. It seems easy but i think it's really tricky. I will just show you the object here because the real one has a lot of other things involved.

This is the object:

```
var data = {
checkboxes: ["A", "B", "C"],
customers : 1,
expDate: 2015
}
```

if i do a simple for loop based on data.checkboxes.length i end up with this:

```
Object {checkboxes: Array["A", "B", "C"], customers: 1, expDate: 2015}
Object {checkboxes: Array["A", "B", "C"], customers: 1, expDate: 2015}
Object {checkboxes: Array["A", "B", "C"], customers: 1, expDate: 2015}
```

as you can see each checkboxes contains 3 items, this is not something that i want. I want each object to have one value from the checkboxes array.

Here is the result i expect to get:

```
Object {checkboxes: "A", customers: 1, expDate: 2015}
Object {checkboxes: "B", customers: 1, expDate: 2015}
Object {checkboxes: "C", customers: 1, expDate: 2015}
```

I don't know but to me it seems very confusing. Maybe you guys have already done similar thing before. I will much appreciate it if you share your thoughts.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use that iterator to access sub-index of checkboxes

```js
var data = {
checkboxes: ["A", "B", "C"],
customers : 1,
expDate: 2015
}

console.log(data);

function getFormattedData()
{
   
  document.write("<p>Printing Results:<br/>");
  
  var results = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < data.checkboxes.length; i++)
  {
    results[i] = data.checkboxes[i] + ", " + data.customers + ", " + data.expDate;  
    document.write(results[i] + "<br/>");
  } 
  
  document.write("</p>");
  
  return results; 
}


getFormattedData();


data.customers = 2;


getFormattedData();
```

*EDIT: made into resusable functions, following comment when questioner*

Comment: This is almost what i wanted i say almost because the perfect case for me would be changing the data object dynamically without having to re-build the object.The object elements may change time to time.

Comment: @itismelito, im not entirely sure on what you mean by update, but a reusable function that just accepts the 'data' parameter (or no parameter if data is declared in parent scope, it doesnt need to be passed in then) and can print this out whereever you need, and/or return 'results' to be handled elsewhere whenever you need. Please update your question with more context if this still somehow isnt enough

Comment: Since you were close to what i wanted let me explain you what is the issue with your option. So basically every object key represent an input field, some are select fields that generate other input fields based on selected fields. So the object it self changes on fly. My idea was to find a way to inject that checkboxes value to whatever the object shape is. In your case i will have to validate first what the object contains and add or remove extra keys. I don't know if i explained well. Let me know if you have an option in mind for that. Thank you.

Comment: @itismelito Ok, i can see what your getting at, but the question never mentioned any of that, at all, so rework the question to show in which way the code will change, else i cant really provide any cachall code example. We need to at least know on which level your adding indexes, how much names and ect expect to change and such - i would recommend tiered approach where any 'dynamic' data contains nested objects, with named indexes for 'type','values',ect. with top level 'fields' as an array of these objects. 'type' would maybe just be "checkbox" | "input" | "radio", values would be array

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is what you want but try out this code.

```
var data = {
  checkboxes: ["A", "B", "C"],
  customers : 1,
  expDate: 2015
}

var result = data.checkboxes.map(function(s) {
  return {
    checkboxes: s,
    customers : data.customers,
    expDate: data.expDate
  };
});
```